# Replacing/changing video background

Tags: editing

How could I replace the background of a video such as the one in the picture
[image]
to a bright white? I have iMovie, is it of any use here?

Comment: Quickest way will be to reshoot it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a tricky one since the background color is the same as the shirt shes wearing.
 This can be achieved Manually by masking your subject frame by frame, if there is no much movement and duration is little then this shouldn't be a problem, although you might have some difficulty with the hair.
**Note:** masking should not be very accurate in this case, make a fast one then feather it and increase the brightness of the layer behind "background" until it becomes bright white and see if you like the result.

Comment: That said, if all the OP has is iMovie, good luck to him.  This is super time consuming under the best of circumstances, I'm not sure if iMovie even has the facilities to deal with this slowly.